# How to create a valid WS-A request with SOAP UI

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui, ws-addressing

My webservice defines a WS Addressing policy in its **WSDL** with

```
<wsp:Policy wss:Id="WSAddressing_policy"
      xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
      xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
      xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
    <wsam:Addressing>
        <wsp:policy/>
    </wsam:Addressing>
</wsp:Policy>
```

... and

```
  <wsdl:binding name="OutboundBinding" type="tns:OutboundPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSAddressing_policy"/>
       <!-- Verify Availability -->        
        <wsdl:operation name="VerifyAvailability">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="VerifyAvailabilityRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="VerifyAvailabilityResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
```

I use **CXFs** automatic interceptors for policies:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <p:policies ignoreUnknownAssertions="true"/>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

Now I'm **unable to create a valid request** to this webservice with SOAP UI - I always get the following response, regardless which WS-A settings I try:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">ns1:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired</faultcode>
         <faultstring>A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I'm also unable to create a valid request using a CXF Client itself. I managed to get it working if I change the WSDL from

```
<wsp:Policy wss:Id="WSAddressing_policy">
    <wsam:Addressing>
        <wsp:policy/>
    </wsam:Addressing>
</wsp:Policy>
```

to

```
    <wsp:Policy wss:Id="WSAddressing_policy">
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" wsp:Optional="false" />
    </wsp:Policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the addressing metadata namespace is currently the problem for CXF. 
I filed a [bugreport](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6605?filter=-2).
Using

xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/0**2**/addressing/metadata"
instead of
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/0**5**/addressing/metadata"
solves the problem.